# Is there any way to change TCP seq and ack status in eBPF?

Tags: tcp, ebpf

I want to use eBPF to reply some packet in a TCP connection. But if I just prepare the reply packet and use `bpf_clone_redirect(skb, skb->ifindex, 0);` to send it back, the TCP connection state will be wrong. This means if I pass the packet in the future to upper, it cannot be handled correctly(because the ack record in kernel is wrong).

I tried to read BPF documentation and search on Google, but get nothing.

So I want to ask is there anyone know related bpf helper functions or related information?

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you want to modify the conntrack state in Linux for a packet you answered at the XDP or tc layer, before going through conntrack?

Comment: @pchaigno Yes, I want to answer the packet meets certain conditions at tc layer and modify the conntrack state of TCP to let it know I have answered the packet. I hope that the packets that do not meet the conditions can continue to be handed over to the upper layer for processing without causing TCP connection errors.

Comment: I would like to give an example to illustrate the problem. For example when the sequence in the sending direction is 10, I found a packet that satisfies the condition and responded with a packet of length 7, and the next packet does not meet my processing condition, I want to hand it over to the upper layer for processing. But because the upper layer doesn't know what happened before, it will continue to use the seq instead of the correct 17. So I want to find a way to let upper know and set the packet seq it sent out to 17.

Comment: I suddenly have a new idea. If all I need to do is to make the seq num right, then I don't need to let TCP know what happened. I just need to record the length of the packet I send and keep modifying the seq of every packet received and sent out. Will this work fine?

Comment: Won't conntrack complain if it doesn't see e.g. the SYN+ACK?